# OpenCV VideoCapture cannot open URL

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, mjpeg

I am trying to open my cam that streams mjpeg.  I am able to access it from my browser

```
VideoCapture cap;
string url = "http://192.168.0.121:8080/?action=stream&x.mjpg";
cap.open(url);
if (!cap.isOpened()){
    cout << "Failed to Open stream" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

This code works on my ubuntu desktop.  When I cross compile and put it in my raspberry pi clone called nanopi it fails with Failed to Open stream.

I am able to open a USB camera in nanopi but not urls.

I tried doing an strace and I saw this

```
open("http://192.168.0.121:8080/?action=stream&x.mjpeg", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
fstat64(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0600, st_rdev=makedev(249, 0), ...}) = 0
ioctl(1, TCGETS, {B115200 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xb6f6e000
write(1, "Failed to Open stream\n", 22Failed to Open stream) = 22
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

> open("http://192.168.0.121:8080/?action=stream&x.mjpeg", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Is it seeing it as a file path instead of a URL?

Please let me know what I can do.

Comment: I think you should search for "mjpeg codec support for raspberry pi"

Comment: it seems i need to build it with ffmpeg support.  thats the difference according to cmake between the opencv version in my desktop and the one in nanopi.  need to figure how to do that...